# Is there anyway to copy linked libraries directly into the executable?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker, dyld

I have a C++ project I'm compiling with CMake. One of the dependencies is LevelDB which I have installed using homebrew. In my CMakeLists.txt I have the following line:

```
target_link_libraries(test /usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/1.23/lib/libleveldb.dylib)
```

The binary that is generated works fine on my computer but it crashes when I run it on a computer that does not have libleveldb installed, stating that the library could not be found.

Is there any way that I could simply bundle the leveldb .dylib file into the executable itself -- this seems like the most reasonable way of making a binary that is simple for the end user to download and run.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to the static library (`libleveldb.a`), not the dynamic one (`libleveldb.dylib`)? The same probably needs to be done with its dependent `libsnappy.a` library as well, I guess.

Comment: @heapunderrun could You please expand on Your comment on the answer section, to finally close this question?